# Download file through webview inside tab with AsyncTask

Tags: android, webview, android-asynctask, download, tabs

I'm developing my very first app and I would like to download some pdf files from urls of a webview , but I have some issues. I tried using setDownloadListener, but although I have several pdf viewers installed on my phone It only let me to open the files with the browser (I can´t use this because login is required in the web, so my app wouldn't be useful) and with OfficeSuite, that have problems opening them due to some issues with the file names (only when downloading), so I thought I could download them through the webview and then open them.
For this, I could use AsyncTask. Following a similar example I think It would be something like this, but I don't know how to implement it:

```
    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    private static final String TAG = "TAG";
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
        InputStream input = null;
        OutputStream output = null;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);
            String filename = url.getFile();
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Server didn't return 200. ");
                // handle error
                return null;
            }

            input = connection.getInputStream();
            output = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + filename); // where to save file

            byte data[] = new byte[4096];
            int count;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                if (isCancelled()) {
                    return null;
                }
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // handle error
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: ", e);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (output != null)
                    output.close();
                if (input != null)
                    input.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "IOException: ", e);
            }

            if (connection != null)
                connection.disconnect();
        }
        return null;

    }
}
```

Mi TabFragment is as follows:

```
public class TabFragment extends Fragment {

@Nullable
@Override
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.web_layout, container, false);
    final WebView webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    //Activate Javascript:
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    //Trying to download pdf:
    webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                    String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                    long contentLength) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    String appCachePath = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(appCachePath);
    //Loading the URL:
    webView.loadUrl("myweb.com");
    //Going back:
    webView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                    webView.goBack();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    return rootView;


    }
}
```

How to implement the AsyncTask to download the files?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved it with DownloadManager